# AttributeError when setting matplotlib style

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python script which uses the following import list:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

It then imports a textfile into a dataframe, creates some additional columns in the df and creates two plots.

I need to be able to call it from Matlab (for a number of tedious reasons...) and I did this by typing the following at the Matlab prompt:

```
dos('myfile.py')
```

Which threw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "D:\Documents\Python Scripts\XXXXXXXXX.py", line 8, in     <module> 
    matplotlib.style.use('ggplot') 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

However if I comment the line asking for the ggplot style, it runs fine and generates the plots correctly in standard matplotlib formatting.

Any suggestions as to why this might be the case?

Best Regards,

Ben

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, no? `matplotlib` doesn't have a `style` attribute. `pyplot`, however, does. If you check the [examples from `matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/style_sheets/plot_ggplot.html), you'll see that you want to use `plt.style.use('ggplot')` instead.

Comment: It is, but I was confused as to why the code worked fine when I ran it in an IPython console and displayed the plots correctly.

Comment: @BMichell the reason it would have worked in IPython is that you ran the maptplotlib magic `%matplotlib` before

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`style` is an attribute of pyplot, not matplotlib

try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```